# How to concatenate 2 integer values into a single string in Spring MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My document in a aggregation stage looks like this:

```
{
    month: 9,
    year: 2017
}
```

Now I would like it to becomes:

```
{
    time: "9/2017"
}
```

In Mongo shell (v3.6.4) I can do this and it works as expected:

```
$concat: [{$substr:["$month", 0, -1]}, "/", {$substr:["$year", 0, -1]}]
```

In version 4.0 there is a `$toString` operator do the same trick `$substr`.

But there are no equivalent in Spring MongoDB, some topics on Stack Overflow use the code `.addExpression("concat(month,'/',year)")`. This code snippet works if only month/year field is a String like `{month: "9"}` but not `{month: 9}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it by myself:

```
project().andExpression("concat(substr(month,0,-1),'/',substr(year,0,-1))").as("time")
```